# Why am I getting a SunCertPathBuilderException when trying to consume data via REST API?

Tags: java, spring, ssl-certificate, resttemplate

I try to consume a REST API via a Rest template.
I add its certificate in my trust store but I have an Exception.

The cert DN is: *.domain.com and I try GET https://api.domain.com

the stack trace:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1284)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
    ... 62 more
```

My service method

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                https://api.domain.com,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                request,
                String.class,
                1
        );
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
```

Have you some idea why this is happening?

Comment: One quick luck check you can try is  to shift to a mobile hotspot or other network which you are sure is not behind any kind of proxy(most company networks have type this issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `X509TrustManagerImpl` has problems to accept the certificate.
This can happen when the TLS certificate is not from a trusted source (e.g. self-signed or just not accepted by java trust store).

I would try to execute your code with another (newer) JDK - e.g. Oracle or Amazon Coretto, where trust stores are maintained and up-to-date.

**When it works with other, newer JDK...**

If this works - TLS certificate seems to be valid. If you need to use your JDK (e.g. license issues) you could import certificate into your local trust store.

**When it also not works with other, newer JDK...**

If this does not work... Look at the certificate and check if it's really trustful... Maybe a security issue... e.g. man in the middle attack (or just a company proxy making odd things with certificates...)

Or ... its just a self signed certificate, e.g. used on a test server. 
**If you are really, really sure that you can trust a self signed certificate** (e.g. when its your own test server), you can either import it into your trust store, or make a TRUST_ALL approach like done in : https://github.com/Daimler/sechub/blob/develop/sechub-adapter/src/main/java/com/daimler/sechub/adapter/support/TrustAllSupport.java

But the correct way would be to just ensure certificates are trustful.